# Syntax in VB Weight Calculator

Tags: vb.net, syntax

I'm writing a really simple weight calculator code -- user inputs weight and height, I calculate standard weight for that height, and the code compares that weight to ranges of weights based on the standard in an if/elseif block.

The standard weight is returned correctly, but the code ALWAYS returns "Normal Weight", regardless of the height to weight ratio. I'm new to VB, so my hunch is it's a relatively simple syntax issue.

```
  Dim dbHeight, dbWeight, dbStWeight As Double
    dbHeight = CDbl(tbxHeight.Text)
    dbWeight = CDbl(tbxWeight.Text)
    dbStWeight = (dbHeight * 30.48 - 105) / 0.454
    lblFeedback.Text = ("Your standard weight is " & dbStWeight)

    If (dbStWeight * 0.9 <= dbWeight <= dbStWeight * 1.1) Then
        lblResult.Text = ("Normal Weight")

    ElseIf (dbStWeight * 1.1 < dbWeight <= dbStWeight * 1.2) Then
        lblResult.Text = ("Over Weight")

    ElseIf (dbStWeight * 0.8 <= dbWeight < dbStWeight * 0.9) Then
        lblResult.Text = ("Under Weight")

    ElseIf (dbWeight > dbStWeight * 1.2) Then
        lblResult.Text = ("Very overweight")

    ElseIf (dbWeight < dbStWeight * 0.8) Then
        lblResult.Text = ("Very underweight")

    End If
    lblFeedback.Refresh()
    lblResult.Refresh()
```

Comment: VB doesn't support multiple conditions quite the way you wrote them. `dbStWeight * 0.9 <= dbWeight <= dbStWeight * 1.1` needs to be split into individual conditions that either `AND`ed or `OR`ed. This applies to the first three IF statements.

Comment: @Martin - so something like If dbStWeight * 0.9 <= dbWeight AND dbWeight <= dbStWeight * 1.1 would work?

Comment: If those are the two conditions, yes. Otherwise, you are implicitly doing some binary operations on Boolean sub-expressions (something along the lines of FALSE < 5).

Comment: But then I still receive "Normal Weight" even if the values are extreme and fall under the last two ElseIf statements

Comment: You need to make sure that all the IF statements are like that. Your first three did that unexpected expression.

Comment: I'm not sure that that's the issue (although it is AN issue). The real problem here is that Vb.net is reading every value I enter as falling into the normal weight category. It seems like a mathematical syntax problem

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger. You can inspect what is being calculated.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uNtuwM#

Comment: When I run it through the debugger it works fine. Maybe it's ArcGis causing the issue

Comment: Got it, thanks @Plutonix

Comment: I'd rather use a [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) for that kind of things https://dotnetfiddle.net/CQ7plN

Comment: I agree, but the OP was having (severe) trouble with the IF logic

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub btOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btOK.Click

    Dim dbHeight, dbWeight, dbStWeight As Double
    dbHeight = CDbl(tbxHeight.Text)
    dbWeight = CDbl(tbxWeight.Text)
    dbStWeight = (dbHeight * 30.48 - 105) / 0.454
    StWeight.Text = ("Your standard weight is " & dbStWeight)

    If (dbStWeight * 0.9 <= dbWeight) AndAlso (dbWeight <= dbStWeight * 1.1) Then
        Result.Text = ("Normal Weight")

    ElseIf (dbStWeight * 1.1 <= dbWeight) AndAlso (dbWeight <= dbStWeight * 1.2) Then
        Result.Text = ("Overweight")

    ElseIf (dbStWeight <= dbWeight) AndAlso (dbWeight < dbStWeight * 0.9) Then
        Result.Text = ("Underweight")

    ElseIf (dbWeight > dbStWeight * 1.2) Then
        Result.Text = ("Very overweight")

    ElseIf (dbWeight < dbStWeight * 0.8) Then
        Result.Text = ("Very underweight")

    End If

End Sub
```